# Displaying only logged in user's records

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to restrict users records display. Basically i am developing a CRM where a user logs in and enters (orders, quotes...) his data and submits to database. So when a user logs in i want to display only those records which he has entered not others data. For this I take user's `session` id and stores it infront of his records,

While displaying i am doing like this

```
"SELECT * FROM orders WHERE user_id='".$_SESIION['userID']."';
```

But i have to do this 'WHERE' for all display function . Instead of that is there any other way i can do this i mean without repetitive `WHERE`statement?

Please suggest

Comment: do the query once and save all the data in the session so that you dont need to query everytime

Comment: @Exprator: Very Sorry, I did not get you

Comment: you said you have to query everytime right? or can you make it a little clear what you want

Comment: Wherever i display the records like in Quotations, orders, invoices... every time i should put `where` condition to display user-related data or is there any other way, may be function or anything ?

Comment: yes you can create a function where in param you pass the id of the user and do the query inside the function, then call the function where you need

Comment: but my table will be different na, `orders`, `quotes`,` invoice`...

Comment: you can get the table name dynamically also, see if the user clicks on order you can get the value and pass it to the sql like the id

Comment: Let me try this!. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question: is there any other way i can do this i mean without repetitive WHEREstatement?
My answer is: There is no!

Help for prepare: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

The database could be like this, for example:

table users

```
id_user email password etc.
```

Table articles

```
id_article title_article body_article id_user etc
```

When you query

```
select * from article where id_users = ?
```

Use prepere

```
insert into articles (............, id_user, ....) values (?, ?, ? etc)
```

All tables, like this one article, can have field id_user, it goes in table with query input ...., by session and prepere protection against SQL injections. And when user select anything, he will have only what he has injected.

Comment: Yeas thats what i was telling. Every table will have `user_id`. But to display `orders`, i should query `select.......from orders where user_id`

for `quotes` again i should user `where`...

it will be repetitive, which i want to minimise

Comment: All is minimized. How many queries = That much where id_user. There is no problem. Every query you code only ones, but query works many times.

Comment: It is only one more WHERE clausula in every query. You think about queries, no problem one more WHERE.

Comment: There are no other ways. If you want queries for id_user, its must bee code WHERE clausula. And it is no repetition of WHERE = every queries there are only one WHERE about id_user.

Comment: ohh. So what i was doing is the only way then!

Comment: Yes @user3368088 that what you was doing is the only way!